# Scala Unit testing for ProcessAllWindowFunction

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

After Reading the official flink testing documentation (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/stream/testing.html)
I was able to develop tests for a ProcessFunction, using a Test Harness, something like this:

```
pendingPartitionBuilder = new PendingPartitionBuilder(":::some_name", "")

testHarness =
  new OneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness[StaticAdequacyTilePublishedData, PendingPartition](
    new ProcessOperator[StaticAdequacyTilePublishedData, PendingPartition](pendingPartitionBuilder)
  )

testHarness.open()
```

now, I’m trying to do the same for a ProcessAllWindowFunction, that looks like this:

```
class MapVersionValidationDistributor(batchSize: Int) extends
  ProcessAllWindowFunction[MapVersionValidation, Seq[StaticAdequacyTilePublishedData],TimeWindow] {

lazy val state: ValueState[Long] = getRuntimeContext .getState(new ValueStateDescriptor[Long]("latestMapVersion", classOf[Long]))
(...)
```

First I realized I can’t use TestHarness for  ProcessAllWindowFunction, because it doesn’t have a processElement method. In this case, what unit test strategy should I follow?

EDIT: At the moment my test code looks like this:

```
val collector = mock[Collector[Seq[StaticAdequacyTilePublishedData]]]
    val mvv = new MapVersionValidationDistributor(1)
    val input3 = Iterable(new MapVersionValidation("123",Seq(TileValidation(1,true,Seq(1,3,4)))))

    val ctx = mock[mvv.Context]
    val streamContext =  mock[RuntimeContext]
    mvv.setRuntimeContext(streamContext)

    mvv.open(mock[Configuration])
    mvv.process(ctx,input3,collector)
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
 Unexpected call: <mock-3> RuntimeContext.getState[T](ValueStateDescriptor{name=latestMapVersion, defaultValue=null, serializer=null}) Expected: inAnyOrder { }
```

Comment: You just want to test the behavior of You process method on some window right ??

Comment: yes, that's basically what I’m trying to do :)
thanks for the reply btw

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need test harness to unit test the `process` method of the `ProcessAllWindowFunction`. The `process` function takes 3 arguments: `Context`, `Iterable[IN]`, `Collector[OUT]`. You can use some library depending on the language used to mock the `Context`. You can also easily implement or mock the `Collector` depending on your prerefences here. And the Iterable[IN] is just an `Iterable` containing the elements of Your window, that would be passed to the function after the window is triggered.

Comment: I did something like you said and i call the function like this:
     `mvv.process(ctx,
      Seq(input,input2,input3),
      collector
    )`
with the ctx and the collector being mocks, the thing is that when i try to run the code I get  this error: 
The runtime context has not been initialized.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The runtime context has not been initialized.

Comment: This exception is thrown when the `RuntimeContext` is `null`. I assume You should mock this too. Are you invoking `getRuntimeContext()` in Your function ??. You can use `setRuntimeContext` to set runtime context after You create new instance of Your function.